# Expected an indented block - driving me mad

Tags: python

```
choice = '' #Initialise choice to blank so will enter loop
print('MAIN MENU')             #---
print('-----------')           #--
print('1) Encrypt a message')  #- Display main menu
print('2) Decrypt a message')  #--
print('3) Exit')               #---
while choice not in ['1','2','3']:
    choice = input('Please choose 1,2 or 3 ')#Get user's choice
    if choice == "1":
        #encrypt() Call encrypt function
    elif choice == '2':
        # decrypt() Call decrypt function
    else:
        sys.exit() #Exit the program
```

Why is this happening no matter what indentation I try I still get the error!
I have looked at other responses but none seem to help - I am sure it is trivial but I have tried loads of configurations but none work

Comment: Use eclips with Pydev it will help a lot for indentation and overall coding !!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a block statement like `if` and `elif`, you must have at least one indented line. Comments do not count, so there are no indented lines here:

```
if choice == "1":
    #encrypt() Call encrypt function
elif choice == '2':
    # decrypt() Call decrypt function
```

You can use a `pass` statement if you don't want to do anything in the block:

```
if choice == "1":
    pass #encrypt() Call encrypt function
elif choice == '2':
    pass #decrypt() Call decrypt function
```

Comment: Well I have learnt something  # comments don't count  thanks I thought I was going mad

Answer (score 3):

You can't have empty if or else block,

```
while choice not in ['1','2','3']:
    choice = input('Please choose 1,2 or 3 ')#Get user's choice
    if choice == "1":
        pass
    elif choice == '2':
        pass
    else:
        sys.exit() #Exit the program
```